# What is the logical objection to the following procedure?

Tags: calculus

This problem is in my textbook and I have no idea what to do with it.

"What is the logical objection to the following procedure? Let $f(x)$ be a given function defined when $a≤x≤b$. Let $F(x)$ be any differentiable function such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for each x of the given interval. Then define $∫_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$"

Isn't that just the first fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: I think this is a badly designed textbook problem, & I’m registering my annoyance here for posterity. First, presumably what the authors are driving at is that this definition isn’t obviously well-defined, but that’s typical in math, & you can easily prove well-definedness using the mean value theorem (at least in the case $f$ is continuous). Second, historically, it is my understanding that this is actually how Newton himself did define the definite integral. It is pretty ridiculous to deprive students of this important historical fact with the dismissive invocation of a “logical objection.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear that this "definition" is in fact well defined.  Suppose $G(x)$ is a different function differentiable on $[a, b]$ such that $G'(x)=f(x)$.  How do you know that $G(b)-G(a)=F(b)-F(a)$?  That requires proof before you can use this as a definition.

**Edited to add:**  The key here is that you were asked to *choose* any possible $F$ (out of multiple possibilities) that fits the conditions and then use that $F$ in subsequent calculations resulting in your definition.  Whenever that happens (and it happens a lot when you define things in terms of equivalence classes), you need to check whether your proposed definition is in fact well defined.  That means you have to show that you end up with the same result no matter which choice you make out of all the eligible candidates.

Comment: +1. To the OP, to drive this point home, think about what would happen if we allowed a "hole" in the domain. In general we can have $F'(x)=G'(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in dom(f)$ but $F-G$ not being constant.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: well, you can’t have a hole for the $f$ specified in the attempted definition because it is stipulated $f$ is defined on an interval. But I gather this is what you meant by “in general.” See also my comment on the OP.

Comment: @symplectomorphic "it is stipulated $f$ is defined on an interval." Hence my "if we allowed." Re: your main comment, I personally disagree: pointing out logical issues with historical approaches doesn't in any way "deprive" us of them. I think developing a critical eye in this regard is actually quite important.

Comment: @Noah: No doubt the critical eye is important; no one could seriously disagree. It’s just that the tone of the problem, which says nothing about history, isn’t to my taste: it doesn’t serve to balance our later perspective with the historical one that got the whole thing going, and there really is no essential logical obstruction for $f$ continuous on an interval. I realize this is a matter of taste, though. IMO the correct pedagogical approach here would be to illustrate why the earlier theory was too limited, not to suggest, w/o context, that it is illogical.

Comment: For the record the problem is in a section dealing with finding out logical inconsistencies and things of that sort. So, while the context was not historical I didn't find it unreasonable to ask a question like this.